# My searchbar Disappears

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

When i segue my search data everything works fine but when i come back from segue my searchbar disappears..any help on what i'm doing wrong and how to fix problem.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
    UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (myCell == nil) {
        myCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]; }

    Location *item;
    if (!isFilltered) {
        item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];
    } else {
        item = [filteredString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    myCell.textLabel.text = item.name;
    myCell.detailTextLabel.text = item.city;
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DemoCellImage"];
    [myCell.imageView setImage:myImage];

    return myCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (!isFilltered)
        _selectedLocation = _feedItems[indexPath.row];
    else
        _selectedLocation = [filteredString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:self];
}
```

here is the prepare to segue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"])
    {
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    LeadDetailViewControler *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    detailVC.selectedLocation = _selectedLocation;
    }
}
```

here is where

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchBar.hidden = YES;
    self.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"name",@"city",@"phone",@"date",@"active"];
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}
- (void)searchButton:(id)sender {

    self.searchBar.hidden = NO;
   [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

     self.searchBar.text=@"";
     self.searchBar.hidden = YES;
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: show how and where you add UISearchBar ..

Comment: it shows in my nav Header

Comment: show how come back from segue...

Comment: i don't have a segue back